# Bootstrap 4 validation - check if at least one field was filled out

Tags: validation, bootstrap-4

On a webform, I want to create a validation (on submit) that will force a user to fill out at least one of two fields, but I would like to do it using the valid/invalid classes that Bootstrap offers.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label for="companyIdId">Company ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyIdId" placeholder="" required="true" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback"> Company Id is mandatory. </div>
        <div class="valid-feedback"> Looks good! </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="CompanyRegNumberId">Company Registration Number</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CompanyRegNumberId" placeholder="" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required="true" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback"> Company Registration Number is mandatory. </div>
            <div class="valid-feedback"> Looks good! </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score -2):

Go look at Bootstrap's [forms](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/?#validation) and just add the provided script